# C# Custom configuration not read

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a program in C# and, for the first time, I use custom configuration.

My program is starting correctly, but the configuration file seems not to be read.

This is my "app.config" configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="Files" type="Initialisation.FilesSection, Initialisation" >
      <section name="Source" type="Initialisation.SourceElement, Initialisation" />

      <section name="List" type="Initialisation.ListElementCollection, Initialisation" />
      <section name="File" type="Initialisation.FileElement, Initialisation" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <Files>
    <Source path="\\192.168.21.6\tmp\" />

    <List>
      <File name="Adobe Reader"       file="readerdc_fr_xa_crd_install.exe"           default="true"  />
      <File name="Adobe Flash"        file="flashplayer27pp_xa_install.exe"           default="false" />
      <File name="Java"               file="java.exe"                                 default="true"  />
    </List>
  </Files>
</configuration>
```

And this is the class, which manages the file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Initialisation
{
    public class Files
    {
        //private static FilesSection _config;

        private Files()
        {
        }

        public static FilesSection Config
        {
            get
            {
                /*if (_config == null)
                {
                    _config = global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Files") as FilesSection;
                }
                return _config;*/
                return ((FilesSection)(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Files")));
            }
        }
    }

    public class FilesSection : System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
    {

        [System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("Source")]
        public SourceElement Source
        {
            get
            {
                return ((SourceElement)(this["Source"]));
            }
        }

        [System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("List")]
        [System.Configuration.ConfigurationCollectionAttribute(typeof(FileElement), AddItemName = "File")]
        public ListElementCollection List
        {
            get
            {
                return ((ListElementCollection)(this["List"]));
            }
        }
    }

    public class SourceElement : System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement
    {

        [System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("path", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Path
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(this["path"]));
            }
            set
            {
                this["path"] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ListElementCollection : System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection
    {

        public FileElement this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                return ((FileElement)(this.BaseGet(i)));
            }
        }

        protected override System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new FileElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((FileElement)(element)).Name;
        }
    }

    public class FileElement : System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement
    {

        [System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("name", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(this["name"]));
            }
            set
            {
                this["name"] = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("file", IsRequired = true)]
        public string File
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(this["file"]));
            }
            set
            {
                this["file"] = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("default", IsRequired = false, DefaultValue = false)]
        public bool Default
        {
            get
            {
                return ((bool)(this["default"]));
            }
            set
            {
                this["default"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get values like this:

```
FilesSection fs = Files.Config;
SourceElement se = fs.Source;
string path = se.Path;

MessageBox.Show(path);
```

But all variables (fs, se and path) are null.

I read many posts, and I already tried many solutions :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the *Files* class is a *ConfigurationSection*, but you are declaring it on your app.config as a *sectionGroup*. The same can be said of the other elements, which are *ConfigurationElement* but are declared as *section* elements.

Remove all *ConfigurationElements* from the *configSections*, as they do not required declaration, and change the Files declaration from *sectionGroup* to *section*.

Your *configSections* should look like this:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="Files" type="Initialisation.FilesSection, Initialisation" />
</configSections>
```